# django/celery data import fails to check for existing data

Tags: django, database, concurrency, celery

I have running celery with django. I import a stream of objects into my database by using tasks. each task imports one object. concurrency is 2. within the stream objects can be duplicated, but should not be inside my database.

code i'm running:

```
if qs.exists() and qs.count() == 1:
    return qs.get()
elif qs.exists():
    logger.exception('Multiple venues for same place')
    raise ValueError('Multiple venues for same place')
else:
    obj = self.create(**defaults)
```

problem is that if objects inside the stream are duplicate and very close to each other, the app still imports the same objects twice.

I assume that the db checks are not working properly with this concurrency setup. what architecture du you recommend to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use locking *architecture*, so will block the the two tasks from executing the object fetching part at the same time, you can use [python-redis-lock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-redis-lock) to do that.

Comment: wow, great advice. will go for it! fyi my interim solution was to put a unique constraint on two cols to have at least ensured that db stays consistent. the raised error kills the celery task. it's for now more a brute force-like attempt.